# How can I stop the effects of the users clicks?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension to edit properties of images that are clicked on. I am using a package called element picker to select the images (this is triggered through an html button in a popup). The code works and I can change the properties of the image. However the package does not stop whatever action is linked to the image, which can often lead to the user being taken to a new page. How can I stop any of the actions of the users click between the time they press the button in the popup and they have selected an image?
Thank you in advance.

```
var elementPicker = require('element-picker')

function onClick(elt) {
    [.....]
}
elementPicker.init({ onClick })
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't usually recommend using this but CSS `pointer-events` can solve this problem. The idea is that any element with `pointer-events:none` will ignore any interactions. This works to block default HTML interactions like `<a>` or `<button>` as well as any javascript actions attached to the element.

This is the technique frequently used with a modal window to prevent clicks from going "through" the area around a modal. It should also work for what you described.

You could either set that style on the image element or on **All Elements** by using the `* {styles...}` selector. If you go the "all" route, you'll need to explicitly re-enable pointer-events on any elements in your extension interface that you still need actionable by using the 'auto' property.

**Remember to reset pointer events when your extension is finished `* {pointer-events: initial;}` or you'll leave the page completely in-actionable.**

Comment: Thank you so much, this solution looks very simple to impement. Will * {pointer-events: initial;} return every pointer event to it's original state or just enable pointer events even if they were disabled from earlier?

Comment: @UrielSasieni  `initial` goes back to the browser default state. So, I suppose instead of setting the style with javascript and then having to reset, you might want to write the CSS selector to the `<style></style>` tag and then simply remove it when you're done. Take a look at [`stylesheet.insertRule(rule,index)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) if you need help doing that.

Comment: I used `document.querySelector('*').style["pointer-events"]='none` and `initial` at the end, I think it should be fine because i think it is quite rare for an element to have pointer-events disabled.

Comment: I would agree as a general practice. But it's always the edge cases that get me. :-)

Comment: It seems like the way that i have coded it has left most cases as the exception! For some reason, the only events that are disabled are explicit-links, but things like links embedded in images and actions like zooming in can still take place.

Comment: Yeah, zoom is, unfortunately, browser level so there might not be a lot you can do about that. When you say embedded links do you mean an image map?

Comment: Yes, and even things like search bars, it only really works on standard hyperlinks for some reason. I wonder how extension like adblocks implement their element pickers in which even hovering of the mouse has no effect.

Comment: Hmm, it should prevent hovers and clicks. I don't know what your layout looks like, but could you add an overlay? Maybe a div with a high z-index and a fixed position that covers the browser window? Make sure that element DOES receive events and maybe even add a javascript click handler with `event.preventDefault()` & `event.preventPropagation()` so you know its grabbing all the events.

Comment: The `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` together with the `pointer-events` prevents any effect of any action, however it also makes it impossible to inspect element and stops the functionality of the element-picker package for which I am doing this all. I also don't know how to stop the `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` to return the page to normal.  Perhaps it would be worth trying to use a different method for picking the elements, but I can't see any other viable options.

Comment: Is there any way I can see what you're working on? I'm imagining something in my head but it's probably off. I would only use preventDefault & stopPropagation on an element you can add to the DOM and then destroy when you're done. That would "reset" the listener...

Comment: Ok, I have just made a github repo (my first one) https://github.com/uridood/Twistr .The js for this bit is in the content.js file but i use browserify too. It's also my first experience with js and html so I apologize if eveything is very messy/ bad practice. I really appreciate your help but dw if you don't want to look through it. Thanks.

Comment: Did you get this figured out? I got busy and forgot to follow up. But I can take a look again now if its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an Event object being passes through to the function then you could use the Event.preventDefault() function.

This function stops any default behavior and allows you to handle the event in your own manner.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault